# In what ways can this song phrase be grammatically parsed? (From "Close to the Edge" by Yes)

Tags: grammar, syntax, parts-of-speech, lyrics, comprehension

In the song, [*Close to the Edge*](https://www.google.com/search?q="Close+to+the+Edge"+lyrics+yes) by Yes (click link to see lyrics), there is a line that I don't understand how to parse grammatically to make sense of it:

- "And assessing points to nowhere, leading every single one"

I'm not looking for an interpretation, but rather, the ways in which it could be grammatically parsed, even if such a parsing may be abstract or senseless.

For example, in the classic sentence, ["Colorless green ideas sleep furiously"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) there is no sensible interpretation, but we can ascribe a grammatical parsing "Pronoun pronoun noun verb adverb" and we can get a sense that ideas, which are both colorless and green, sleep in a furious way.

There are probably a few ways that the above phrase from the *Yes* song can be parsed, but it's probably limited to a small handful.  It might require some back reference to a prior line, especially the first line.  Again, [the full lyrics can be found here](https://www.google.com/search?q="Close+to+the+Edge"+lyrics+yes).

In other words, what are the possible/probable syntax trees related to this phrase?   (But I need a beginner's explanation.)  I'm just totally lost on it, and that prevents me from even getting to "step 2" of considering any kind of *interpretation*, which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: "points" is probably a verb.  [Taking an assessment [of something unnamed] ] points to [ nothing ].  ...That said, I am a native speaker, and that entire verse makes 0 (zero) sense.  You don't need help with the English - you need to talk to the songwriter.

Comment: @fill I have asked what I think is an acceptable version of the question.

Comment: @Adam Well, actually I think the only reason why you regard it as off-topic is because you are a native speaker. Let me explain this: When you read poetry there are many interpretations, thats true, but even though you don't understand it, you can say with 100% certainty that **some** interpretations are complete BS. I can't. I'm neither a mothertongue speaker nor at a very high level (so I didn't internalize it). Therefore, if **I** read a poem that I don't understand it's more confusing to me because I maybe don't even see a starting point for interpretation. For example you helped me with

Comment: your first comment even though you did not interprete anything.

Comment: @CarSmack ok, your formulation is clearer ...

Comment: Also **fill** I happened to disagree with @Adam when I looked at the phrase, because I interpreted *point* to be a noun. So you see two native speakers are disagreeing over the meaning of just one word.

Comment: +1 to reopen.  I have updated the question to that which I think is the essence of what the OP was asking, and to which I think there is a fact based answer. @CarSmack

Comment: I voted to reopen after reading over the context. I do think there are some objective things that can be said, e.g. if "every single one" refers to points, then points can't be a verb.

Comment: @ColleenV That's one way to parse it.  There are others as well.  That's my point.  List the various ways to parse it.  Let the OP (or anyone else) think of possible interpretations (including abstract or nonsensical) on their own based on the various possible ways to parse it.

Comment: Hi, @fill If you have moment, can you go to [the post I made about your questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43905/meaning-of-assessing-points-to-nowhere/44341) and then tell me which answer you think is best? But only do this if you have time to carefully read each answer... thanks. This might help me choose which answer I think is best.

Comment: @CarSmack: I've made up my mind now and it has not been an easy decision: CoolHandLois's answer. Although I really like ScotM's answer, I understood more after I had read the former and I really appreciate his idea to use the original lyrics.

Comment: fill then you should upvote his answer and maybe leave @CoolHandLouis a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A seasoned witch could call you from the depths of your disgrace
And rearrange your liver to the solid mental grace
And achieve it all with music that came quickly from afar
And taste the fruit of man recorded losing all against the hour
And assessing points to nowhere, leading every single one
```

I'm not familiar with this artist or the history of this song, so the following could be wrong or inaccurate.

You're probably wondering in the last line if *assessing* is the verb, making the last line a dependent clause of the first line, or if *points* is the verb, making the last line able to stand out on its own as a sentence.

It's entirely possible the ambiguity is intentional, since this is a work of art and the lyrics, in my opinion, have a dissociative tone to them.

I'm led to believe *points* is a plural noun and not a verb because *leading every single one* makes sense as a modifier or qualification of what *points* are.  Modifiers are generally close to the words they modify in English.

If *points* is the verb, then *leading every single one* would, from how I see it, link all the way back to *depths of your disgrace*.  You don't really "lead" depths - you're at the bottom of them if you are falling from somewhere - unless you're climbing out of them (which *may* be implied by *call*, however ...)